# Как доказать, что дробь иррационального числа непериодическая?

Tags: математика

Все знают, что дробь иррационального числа - бесконечная непериодическая.

Но как собственно эту непериодичность доказать?
Попытался обратиться к Google, но не нашел ответа.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Любая периодическая дробь представима в виде отношения двух целых чисел. Иррациональное число не представимо по определению. Такого доказательства будет достаточно? :)

Comment: Это следует из теоремы: любая бесконечная периодическая десятичная дробь представляет рациональное число. Доказательство гуглится http://scask.ru/q_book_dr.php?id=13 - соответственно, иррациональным числам остаётся быть только непериодическими без вариантов

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Практически по определению.

Если число представимо в виде конечной десятичной дроби, вроде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то его можно записать так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так что оно рациональное.

Если число представимо в виде периодической дроби, то мы имеем дело с бесконечной геометрической прогрессией, сумма которой - рациональное число:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Осталось доказать обратное - что если число иррациональное, то оно не представимо в виде бесконечной периодической дроби. Идем от противного - пусть есть такое иррациональное число, которое можно представить конечной или бесконечной периодической дробью. Тогда, как уже доказали это число рациональное, а значит, получаем противоречие. Поэтому иррациональное число нельзя представить ни конечной, ни бесконечной периодической дробью. Остается только бесконечная непериодическая дробь.

Comment: В прямом доказательстве есть небольшой изъян - утверждение "если дробь бесконечная и непериодическая - это число иррациональное" не следует из написанного - а *вдруг* есть такое иррациональное, которое представиио в виде периодической дроби? Но это неважно, потому что если убрать это предложение, то вы доказали именно то, что просил ТС - что из иррациональности следует непериодичность. Доказывать, что из рациональности следует периодичность, вас не просили :)

Comment: @Harry Да, согласен, спасибо. Убрал эту фразу.